# Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a composable function that i need to call after clicking a button but it keeps showing an error that composables cannot be executed from button clicks , can anyone please guide me to solve this issue Thank you

- This is my code

```
  Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
               Button(onClick = {
                    // This is a composable function that i need to call
                    SignUpNewUser(email,fullName,country,password)
                }
                ,modifier = Modifier
                       .width(200.dp)
                       .background(color = Color.DarkGray)) {
                Text(text = "Sign Up",style = TextStyle(color = Color.White,fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold))
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can only add a `@Composable` view to another `@Composable` view.

`onClick` is not marked `@Composable`, so you get this warning. You can only change the state with `onClick`.

For example, you can create a flag and display the UI depending on that flag:

```
var signUp by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
if (signUp) {
    SignUpNewUser(email, fullName, country, password)
} else {
    Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
        Button(onClick = {
            signUp = true
        }, modifier = Modifier
            .width(200.dp)
            .background(color = Color.DarkGray)) {
            Text(text = "Sign Up", style = TextStyle(color = Color.White, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold))
        }
    }
}
```

I suggest you start with [this youtube video](https://youtu.be/mymWGMy9pYI) which explains the basic principles of when you need to use state in compose. You can continue deepening your knowledge with state in Compose [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state).

Another option would be to use [Compose Navigation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation).