# How to remove the @Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function in android jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to use remember from jetpack compose in order to change the background colour of the Elevated button when it's clicked . So, when I set a variable with a value of MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary, it's showing error at colorScheme similarly its showing the same error for MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondary . So, I don't quite understand where am I going wrong. I am relatively new to the Jetpack compose. Below is my code.

MainActivity.kt

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.material3.ElevatedButton
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.example.compose.ui.theme.ComposeTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            ComposeTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                MyApp(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize())
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyApp(modifier: Modifier=Modifier,
          names:List<String> = listOf("World","Compose")
){
   Column(modifier = modifier.padding(vertical = 4.dp)) {
       for (name in names) {
           Greeting(name = name)
       }
   }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String) {

    // Define a state to hold the button color
    var buttonColor by remember {
        mutableStateOf(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary)  //colorScheme is giving error
    }

    Surface(
        color = buttonColor,
    modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 4.dp, horizontal = 8.dp)) {
        Row(modifier = Modifier.padding(24.dp)) {
            Column(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)){
                Text(text = "Hello")
                Text(text = name)
        }
            ElevatedButton(onClick = {
                buttonColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondary //colorScheme is giving error
           }) {

                Text(text = "Show more")
            }

        }

    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    ComposeTheme {
        MyApp()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem this way:

```
@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String) {

    val primaryColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
    val secondaryColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondary

    var isSelected by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Surface(
        color = if (isSelected) primaryColor else secondaryColor,
        modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 4.dp, horizontal = 8.dp)
    ) {
        Row(modifier = Modifier.padding(24.dp)) {
            Column(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)) {
                Text(text = "Hello")
                Text(text = name)
            }
            ElevatedButton(colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                if (isSelected) secondaryColor else primaryColor
            ), onClick = {
                isSelected = !isSelected
            }
            ) {
                Text(text = "Show more")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This changes the color of the Surface and the color of the Button every time the button is clicked.

Comment: Thank you so much..it's working, could you tell me why my code was giving an error?

Comment: If you look into your Theme.kt file, you will see that your Theme is a Composable (@Composable). That's why it was showing an error. This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71535932/5513788